# Connecting to OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, tls

HI all , 
i've installed OpenVPN and configured it on my server , got all the files needed , i have a mobilephone 'Nokia N900' it has an OpenVPN applet , i uploaded all the files to the mobile and configured the applet , it connects then says "tls error" ... any clues how to fix that or what is the problem ?

I've already added the port in the firewall .

And how can i connect to OpenVPN from windows machine ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Windows client can be found here: http://openvpn.se/

Are you able to connect to the OpenVPN server from another computer (outside/inside) your network?

Answer (score 0):

for n900 problem - you might be better off asking at maemo-specific groups.

for windows - openvpn works pretty well, i'm using it without problems on xp/vista/windows 7 machines. check for instance [this](http://www.runpcrun.com/howtoopenvpn) tutorial. you will need to run openvpn-gui in elevated privileges mode to be able to alter the routing table. i also needed to do switch to [xp compatibility mode](http://www.fiberworks.com/DNN/Support/OpenVPN/tabid/171/language/en-US/Default.aspx) to run it fine under windows 7.